# style element into intelxdk appframework app according to os theme

Tags: intel-xdk, appframework

in a Intel-Xdk AppFramework 3 application i would like to style a card element according to the current os Theme.

I want the Header of the card to be the same color of the header of the page , how do i do?

card:

```
<div class="widget uib_w_2 widget-container content-area vertical-col  uib-card d-margins section-dimension-2 cpad-1" data-uib="layout/card" data-ver="0">
                <section class="card-header widget-container content-area vertical-col">card header</section>
                <p>card content</p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The card element in Intel XDK's App designer is not part of the AppFramework UI elements, its a custom element for all frameworks, so you have manually add set a class and add css to match the frameworks header color :(

Checkout example css for osTheme [here](https://github.com/01org/appframework/blob/master/build/af.ui.css) and add custom css like this:

```
.ios7 .card-header {...}
.android .card-header {...}
...
```

Comment: Maybe i dont need to use a card, what i need is to represent a list of data, into a web app i would use a table, but in phone app there no avaible space for 7 columns. I'm thinking to make a 2 column table for each item, firse field for name, second field for value.